# Centering a <div> inside a popup <div>

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue figuring out how to center a `<div>` within a `<div>` that popped up after clicking a button.

Not my example, but similar. HTML:

```
<div class="popup">
    <div class="options">
        <div class="option">
            <span id="1">1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="option">
            <span id="2">2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="option">
            <span id="3">3</span>
        </div>
        <div class="option">
            <span id="4">4</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <div id="persona">
        <span id="5">5</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.popup
{
    background-color: #e3ddd1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    top: 10%;
    height: 400px;
    width: 500px;
}
#persona
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

The overlay is just used to fade out the background, and then the popup appears on top of it.
The issue is in the `#persona` block, how do I get it so that `<div id="persona">` is centered within the popup?

Comment: You have some errors in your html. Please fix them and post a jsfiddle if is possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=center+div

Comment: Second @AlexChar (though a Stack Snippet would be even better :D), in addition there's some CSS that makes it so your code doesn't repro the issue (e.g. `display: none;`). In any case, I think the `#persona` `div` *is* centered but just full-width. If you want to center its contents you'll have to do just that; otherwise you need a width less than 100%.

Comment: I have edited the original post. Basically I need to center the <div id="persona">, not just the text within the <div>

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS. [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6rjh9fc2/)

```
.overlay
{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.popup
{
    background-color: #e3ddd1;
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -500px;
    margin-top: -200px;
    height: 400px;
    width: 1000px;
}
#persona
{
    display: table-cell;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```